# Trying to update object within state but bug won't let me do so?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a todo list. I am trying to implement a feature where when the todo is hovered on (li element), a Remove button will appear. However, the only way I can get it to work is to update the main state by adding a "Hover:false" state and updating it that way, but that makes ALL the remove buttons appear on hover.

What I want is for e.g, hover on the second todo, and only that todo's remove button shall appear and the rest remains hidden. How would I implement this into my function?

Here is my code so far

```
  import React from "react";
  import { isTemplateElement, tsStringKeyword } from "@babel/types";

  class TodoListt extends React.Component {
    state = {
      userInput: '',
      todos: [],
      editMode: false,
      hover: false
    }

    hoverOn = (index) => {
      const todos = [...this.state.todos];
      const updatedTodos = todos.map((todo, todoIndex) => {
        if (index == todoIndex) {
          return {
            ...todos,
            hover: true
          };
        } else {
          return todo;
        }
      })
      this.setState({
        todos: updatedTodos
      })
    }

    hoverOff = () => {
      console.log("Not Hovering");
    }

    handleChange(e, index) {
      this.setState({
        userInput: (e)
      })
      console.log(this.state.userInput)
    }


    handleSubmit(e, index) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const { todos, userInput } = this.state;
      this.setState({
        todos: [...todos, {
          text: userInput,
          key: Date.now(),
          editMode: false,
          hover: false
        }],
        userInput: ''
      }
      )
    }

    handleDelete(index) {
      const todos = [...this.state.todos];
      todos.splice(index, 1);
      this.setState({
        todos
      })
    }

    handleEdit(index) {
      const todos = [...this.state.todos];
      const updatedTodos = todos.map((todo, todoIndex) => {
        if (index == todoIndex) {
          return {
            ...todos,
            editMode: true
          };
        } else {
          return todo;
        }
      });
      this.setState(
        {
          ...this.state,
          todos: updatedTodos
        },
        () => console.log(this.state)
      );

    }

    handleUpdateChange = (e, index) => {
      const todos = [...this.state.todos];
      const updatedTodos = todos.map((todo, todoIndex) => {
        if (index == todoIndex) {
          return {
            ...todo,
            text: e.target.value
          };
        } else {
          return todo;
        }
      });
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        todos: updatedTodos
      });
    };



    render() {
      return (

        < div className="test">
          <form onSubmit={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control mb-2"
              placeholder="enter a todo..."
              onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e.target.value)}
              value={this.state.userInput}
            />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </form>

          <ul class="list-group">

            {this.state.todos.map((todos, index) => (

              this.state.editMode[index] ?
                <div>
                  <input type="text" defaultValue={todos.text} />
                </div>
                :


                <li
                  key={todos.key}
                  className="list-group-item w-100"
                  onMouseEnter={(index) => this.hoverOn(index)}
                  onMouseLeave={(index) => this.hoverOff(index)}
                  onDoubleClick={(index) => this.handleEdit(index)}>
                  {todos.text}
                  <div class="delButton">
                    <button className={todos.hover ? "visable" : "notVisable"} onClick={(index) => this.handleDelete(index)}>Remove</button>
                  </div>
                </li>
            )
            )
            }

          </ul>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
  export default TodoListt;
```

Comment: I'd try breaking out the `li` as a separate component and encapsulate your logic there so each Todo has it's own state.

Comment: Hey Donnie! Just wrote you another answer that follows-up from your question yesterday about accessing a prop in the array. Let me know if you have any questions. I broke up the code into parts so that you have an individual Todo component for each item :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create this behaviour easily with css. Give your list-item and your button a classname and then like this:

```
.myButton {
     display: none;
 }

 .myListItem:hover > .myButton {
     display: block;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not the button is displayed should be in state. This state isn't directly related to the `TodoList` but rather each item in the list, it would make sense to make each `li` it's own Stateful React component. Then each component could keep track of its own hover state.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider refactoring the code in TodoList so that you can render an individual Todo component for each added item.

This way the Todo component has its own piece of state to manage, making it easier to for you to build more features off it.

I'm working off the code I provided for you yesterday, but here is essentially what you need to accomplish this.

Here is the sandbox for your reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/1n1c9

### TodoList

```
import React from "react";
import Todo from "./Todo";

class TodoListt extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userInput: "",
      todos: [],
      editMode: false
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
    this.handleEdit = this.handleEdit.bind(this);
    this.handleUpdateChange = this.handleUpdateChange.bind(this);
    this.handleUpdateSubmit = this.handleUpdateSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(e, index) {
    this.setState({
      userInput: e
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(e, index) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { todos, userInput } = this.state;
    this.setState(
      {
        todos: [
          ...todos,
          {
            text: userInput,
            key: Date.now(),
            editMode: false
          }
        ],
        userInput: ""
      },
      () => console.log(this.state)
    );
  }

  handleDelete(index) {
    const todos = [...this.state.todos];
    console.log(index);
    todos.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({
      todos
    });
  }

  handleEdit(index) {
    const todos = [...this.state.todos];
    const updatedTodos = todos.map((todo, todoIndex) => {
      if (index == todoIndex) {
        return {
          ...todo,
          editMode: true
        };
      } else {
        return todo;
      }
    });
    this.setState(
      {
        ...this.state,
        todos: updatedTodos
      },
      () => console.log(this.state)
    );
  }

  handleUpdateChange = (e, index) => {
    const todos = [...this.state.todos];
    const updatedTodos = todos.map((todo, todoIndex) => {
      if (index == todoIndex) {
        return {
          ...todo,
          text: e.target.value
        };
      } else {
        return todo;
      }
    });
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      todos: updatedTodos
    });
  };

  handleUpdateSubmit(e, index) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const todos = [...this.state.todos];
    const updatedTodos = todos.map((todo, todoIndex) => {
      if (index == todoIndex) {
        return {
          ...todo,
          editMode: false
        };
      } else {
        return todo;
      }
    });
    this.setState(
      {
        ...this.state,
        todos: updatedTodos
      },
      () => console.log(this.state)
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control mb-2"
            placeholder="enter a todo..."
            onChange={e => this.handleChange(e.target.value)}
            value={this.state.userInput}
          />
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>

        <ul class="list-group">
          {this.state.todos.map((todos, index) => {
            return (
              <Todo
                todos={todos}
                todoIndex={index}
                handleUpdateSubmit={this.handleUpdateSubmit}
                handleUpdateChange={this.handleUpdateChange}
                handleEdit={this.handleEdit}
                handleDelete={this.handleDelete}
              />
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default TodoListt;
```

### Todo

```
import React from "react";

class Todo extends React.Component {
  state = {
    hovered: false
  };

  handleMouseEnter = () => {
    this.setState({
      hovered: true
    });
  };

  handleMouseLeave = () => {
    this.setState({
      hovered: false
    });
  };

  render() {
    const {
      todos,
      todoIndex,
      handleUpdateSubmit,
      handleUpdateChange,
      handleEdit,
      handleDelete
    } = this.props;

    const { hovered } = this.state;
    return (
      <div
        onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter}
        onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave}
      >
        {todos.editMode ? (
          <form onSubmit={e => handleUpdateSubmit(e, todoIndex)}>
            <input
              value={todos.text}
              onChange={e => handleUpdateChange(e, todoIndex)}
            />
          </form>
        ) : (
          <li
            key={todos.key}
            class="list-group-item"
            onDoubleClick={() => handleEdit(todoIndex)}
          >
            {todos.text}
            <div
              class="delButton"
              style={{ display: hovered ? "block" : "none" }}
            >
              <button
                class="btn btn-danger"
                onClick={() => handleDelete(todoIndex)}
              >
                Remove
              </button>
            </div>
          </li>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Todo;
```